# How do you insert ranks into a table in SQLite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have found a way to rank values in my table, but I am having trouble inserting them because they compose a list.

When I try to refer to the first item, as in using [0], Python apparently identifies it as a dictionary. Therefore, when I run the "UPDATE" command, the rank value cannot be inserted even though the value itself is actually correct.

```
rows = db.execute("SELECT Current_Rank, Country FROM Current_Rankings WHERE user_id=:user_id ORDER BY Current_Rank", user_id=session["user_id"])
    current_rank = db.execute("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM Current_Rankings t2 WHERE t2.Estein_points < t1.Estein_points AND user_id=:user_id) Current_rank FROM Current_Rankings t1 ORDER BY Estein_points", user_id=session["user_id"])
    n = 0
    for row in rows:
        db.execute("UPDATE Current_Rankings SET current_rank = :current_rank WHERE user_id=:user_id", current_rank=current_rank[0], user_id=session["user_id"])
        n += 1
```

I am expecting every value in the table to be ranked according to "Estein_points", but nothing in the table changes when I run the displayed code. Instead, I get the following error message:

```
RuntimeError: unsupported value: {'Current_rank': 1}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the rows returned by those second two selects... Why do you even have them? And the rows from the first one are of course ordered by `current_rank` like that select says to do

Comment: You mention "inserting", referring to the ranks "as in using [0]" and running an "UPDATE", yet the example code has none of those features.  All you show is a few select statements.  There is no way to help if you don't include code relevant to the details in the question.

Comment: I apologize, see the updated code and error message above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the revised question makes a lot more sense and shows what you're trying to do better.

I'm not really fluent in python, but I feel like you should be using a cursor object to execute that query, `fetchone()` to get the first (And only) row of results, and then `thatrow[0]` to get the actual value you want?

Better yet, you can just calculate the rankings on the fly and save a lot of trouble and complication, instead of having to make sure they're updated every time you insert, delete, or modify a row:

With modern versions of sqlite (3.25 and newer), using the `rank()` [window function](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#biwinfunc) :

```sql
SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY Estein_points) AS Current_Rank
     , Country
FROM Current_Rankings
WHERE user_id = :user_id
ORDER BY Current_Rank;
```

With older versions where you have to use a correlated subquery:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT count(*) + 1
        FROM Current_Rankings AS t2
        WHERE t2.Estein_points < t.Estein_points AND t2.user_id = t.user_id) AS Current_Rank
     , Country
FROM Current_Rankings AS t
WHERE user_id = :user_id
ORDER BY Current_Rank;
```

An index on `Current_Rankings(user_id, Estein_points)` will be helpful for both versions.

---

[db<>fiddle example for both](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7fa9b3b16cbbd49e590d8355a4a1044a), plus versions that return rows for all user ids, not just a specific one.

Comment: What does "name" refer to in the bottom instance?

Comment: @FranklinEstein Twas a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: When I try that, the value for Current_Rank is still NULL. I removed the initial value for Current_Rank by the way.

Comment: @FranklinEstein You would use a different name for the ranking if you still have a column by that name in the table, of course.

Comment: Well yes, but the problem is, that when I try to print the table in that case, SQLite does not identify a "Current_Rank" column.

Comment: @FranklinEstein Updated with link to [working demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=48387fce5c79724719844e3e28cd9963)

Comment: I followed your example, but when I try to select "Current_rank" from "Current_Rankings", Python still apparently does not identify the "Current_rank" column.

Comment: @FranklinEstein Are you sure you're giving that column the right name? And how are you trying to get values? Your code in the question didn't look right; if you're trying to do something along the same lines, it wouldn't be surprising if it doesn't work. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) for examples of the proper work flow for getting rows from a query using one of the `fetchXXX()` methods or in a for loop.

Comment: I gave the column the correct name, and the column does not even show up in the SQL table (apart from the way that I am trying to select the values).

Comment: @FranklinEstein Er... The ranks are computed in the select as needed, not stored in a table.

Comment: Well, thank you very much for your help and for typing up the code, but I had no problem computing the rank in the first place. The issue that I am having is placing the correct values in the table.